# Displaying textview settext very slow performance with long text

Tags: textview, android, systrace

I try to display a long text with TextView in Android app (maximally about 300 KB) and performance on Nexus 7 is terrible (something around 10 seconds). Text is scrollable so we divided it into smaller pieces and tried to display them in ListView (using ViewHolder pattern). Performance goes up, but still scrolling animation is VERY choppy. Actually, performance with pure text is unacceptable (Nexus 7 is not the slowest device) but in the end we will use styled text (using SpannableString) which will completely kill performance.

I show systrace screens below (links actually, sorry for that but I have no reptutation to upload pictures :)):

- http://i62.tinypic.com/2mq57qx.png
- http://i60.tinypic.com/mbin1e.png

I know that text rendering is non-trivial task, but iOS deals with it perfectly, so why Android can't? And is there any reasonable solution to this problem?

Hardware acceleration is enabled.

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder = null;
    if (convertView == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.element_item_layout, parent, false);
        //element_item_layout file is/contains only one TextView, as below
        holder.textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.element_item_textview);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
    }

    holder.textView.setText(getItem(position).longText);

    return convertView;
}

private class ViewHolder {
    public TextView textView;
}
```

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: private class ViewHolder extends ViewHolder {}
How this is possible??

Comment: sorry, this was a typo after cleaning a code for this question purpose, corrected

Comment: Ok. Not tried your code since I don't have that LONG text. Your idea of "divided it into smaller pieces" is good but don't implement it with listview, instead create root ScrollView with as per your pieces TextView. Just a suggestion.

Comment: It does seem to be spending a lot of time in getDisplayList().  Out of curiosity, what happens if you *disable* hardware acceleration?

Comment: @Chitrang tried this. Single big TextView in ScollView renders about 10 sec as in question. When divided, it will add all views and render all of them, even if they are not shown, so it takes even longer (whole container in scrollView is rendered). List is scrolling smoothly then, but while creating it takes about 15 sec. addView indicates drawing View, so it can't be placed in any separated Thread (AsyncTask), it must be called in UI thread.

Comment: @fadden getDisplayList and obtainView take most time. getDisplayList() creates display list for new TextView (draw call is necessary) and that's OK but why text drawing takes so long? Pure Canvas.drawText method behaves exactly the same. But I think you've made very good point, because disabling hardware acceleration didn't change anything.

Comment: We use TextView because WebView has been too much pain in the ass already

Comment: :( I take lack of good answer as a next evidence that unfortunately Android is far behind iOS in terms of UI API

Comment: I've found that calling `setText` on an element without fixed dimensions is surprisingly expensive: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10804436/simple-textview-settext-causes-40-cpu-usage
As such, I recommend making sure all the TextViews have fixed layout_width and layout_height. That should at least help a bit.

Comment: @r00dY Did you find any good solution..,I am sailing in the same boat :(
setText() taking a huge time..

Comment: @eRaisedToX Nope, but didn't look into the issue for quite a long time. My case was reader app and to be honest if I could go back in time, I'd go with WebView today.

Comment: Ohk !! thanks for the response.. :)

Comment: @r00dY I guess you were doing the Android Nanodegree - I am doing the very same reader app project now (Make your app material) and stumbled upon this question...